# Weird C# syntax

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I've just found this syntax:

```
date1 = date2?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ?? date3;
```

Of course, being the first time I saw such a syntax, I did not understand it. After debugging, I understood that it is equivalent to:

```
if(date2 != null)
   date1 = date2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
else
   date1 = date3;
```

My question is: why was this syntax introduced, since it is not legible at all, and it just economizes 3 lines of text?

Edit: my question is about the ? operator, not ??

Comment: new syntax is much easier to understand I guess

Comment: It is C# 6.0 syntax

Comment: it's only will tke time to understand after that it will be mutch easyer to read

Comment: Which bit of syntax are you referring to? The `?.` operator or `??`?

Comment: Its just a syntax sugar. Saving us lazy programmers few lines to write.

Comment: Basically the `?.` prevents an exception from occurring when `date2` is null and trying to call `.ToString()` on it. The `??` means that if the left hand side returns null, return the right hand side instead.

Comment: In my opinion, the major difference between the _?./??_ syntax and the _if_-statement is not its shortness and not even its readability, but the fact that it is an expression. This helps you to express yourself in a functional style.

Comment: I think this was one of the most requested features on Roslyn GitHub that and tuples.

Comment: @Lee I was talking about the ?. operator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That statement doesn't just economize 3 lines, it more readable and also spares a code block, which is important to allow more complex LINQ queries.

What do you think of these two?

```
var x = collection.Select(x => new SomeClass(x?.Property ?? "default"));
```

Opposed to:

```
var x = collection.Select(x => 
                               {
                                   string value = null;
                                   if (x != null)
                                   {
                                       value = x.Property;
                                   }

                                   if (value == null)
                                   {
                                       value = "default";
                                   }

                                   return new SomeClass(value);
                               }
                         );
```

The first is much more expressive and powerful. And what if you have more than one property?

Comment: Doesn't the `x?.Property` first confirm `x` is not null before accessing `.Property` to avoid a null reference exception?

Comment: @Forty3 Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2):

They introduced the `?.` operator for the same reason that they introduced the `??` operator: to shorten the code. The same argument you made against `?.` could be made against `??` (and to a lesser degree could be made against the ternary operator `? :`). But in the end I consider it useful (in the same way that I consider it useful the ternary operator `? :`). It is readable if you know what it means. If you don't know what it means any operator is unreadable.

It is useful because the code that you wrote is correct only if `date2` is a field/local variable/parameter... If it is a property, there is a guarantee that the property isn't read twice (something that could be quite important, depending on how the parameter is calculated). The code is changed to something like:

```
DateTime? temp = date2;
string date1 = temp != null ? temp.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : date3;
```

so it can get a little more complex than you thought.

Answer (score 1):

This type of syntax was newly added with C# 6.0.
`?.` is called **null-conditional**.
This [microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) describes all newly added features of C# 6.0 and also lists this new **null-conditional** operator.